# Rest Assured Login test

Tags: rest-assured

I have to perform login test. For this, I create a string containing username and password and then convert it to bytes. I then pass this as body. But, I get the error that the credentials are invalid.

String dataString = "user=" + email + "&password=" +java.net.URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");

body(dataString)

Comment: so do you expect the value for password to go as \x70\x61\x73\x73 ?

Comment: There are 3 types of auth schemes(basic, token and oAuth). Depending on that the code for login will change. Please share the authentication scheme of your application.

Comment: this is the curl i am working on

Comment: curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' -d 'oldValue={some_value}&newValue={some_value}' 'some url'